# How to find string between / / and replace in another place ??? using .bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I m trying to compile batch file to find a string (inside /  /)on a txt file and when it finds get save into variable and replace into next to NCLR I mentioned below example (using .bat script)

****example using .bat script****

**input**

name.txt

```
:61:1508080808C26292,00NCLROTHERS
 /835502/SBI 
:86:THANE - GOKHALE ROAD
/835502/SBI                                      <---- I want to get 835502 string placed inside /835502/ in before line
```

**output**

name.txt

```
:61:1508080808C26292,00NCLR835502                 <----------shoud replace others to copied string


 /835502/SBI 
:86:THANE - GOKHALE ROAD
/835502/SBI
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? please provide your code... you should also reformat your sample text files so that contained line-breaks are visible...

Comment: @sameer basha al-safah :), its not clear what you are trying to do here, if you could explain what exactly you want, that would be great because honestly after looking at your input file and your output file, i didnt exactly understand what you did, so yah, regards!

Comment: You have two terms the same `/835502/` and one of them is copied.  It's not clear from your example if the data is wrong or not.

Comment: Hi what i am trying to say..

Comment: Hi what i am trying to say..  (name.txt is my input ok..Now you can check the input one line called ":61:1508080808C26292,00NCLROTHERS
 /835502/SBI " my requirement is I need to run bat programming the number mentioned inside /835502/ <--- the number (835502) should be place next to NCRL insted of OTHERS in my output file " :61:1508080808C26292,00NCLR835502
 /835502/SBI " Say for an example My input is ":61:1508080808C26292,00NCLROTHERS
 /835502/SBI " and required output is " :61:1508080808C26292,00NCLR835502
 /835502/SBI "